# Android material design - Material Motion

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-animation, android-design-library

I want to make an app which contains list of items. When the user clicks an item, I want to animate it with material motion effect described in [here](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-what-makes-a-good-transition)

Is android libraries contains it as natively? If not, is there a 3. party library for this animation?

You can see the animation in this video: 
[video link](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B14F_FSUCc01aHJmMm9aR3JvazQ/GoodTransition_QuickDo-v4.mp4)

Comment: Refer **Start an activity with a shared element** section at https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use shared element Transition

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActivitySceneTransitionBasic

https://github.com/toddway/MaterialTransitions

https://github.com/afollestad/shared-element-transition-samples

```
FirstFragment fragmentOne = ...;
SecondFragment fragmentTwo = ...;
// Check that the device is running lollipop
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // Inflate transitions to apply
    Transition changeTransform = TransitionInflater.from(this).
          inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);
    Transition explodeTransform = TransitionInflater.from(this).
          inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode);

    // Setup exit transition on first fragment
    fragmentOne.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransform);
    fragmentOne.setExitTransition(explodeTransform);

    // Setup enter transition on second fragment
    fragmentTwo.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeTransform);
    fragmentTwo.setEnterTransition(explodeTransform);

    // Find the shared element (in Fragment A)
    ImageView ivProfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);

    // Add second fragment by replacing first 
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragmentTwo)
            .addToBackStack("transaction")
            .addSharedElement(ivProfile, "profile");
    // Apply the transaction
    ft.commit();
}
else {
    // Code to run on older devices
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]